# Out of swap space

Tags: java, out-of-memory, jvm-crash, g1gc

We are facing following exception. Please not that we are following configurations for the JVM (32 bit )

```
-Xms1024m -Xmx3076m -Xmn1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=8000 
-XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

We are using 32 bit solaris machine .

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 98304 bytes for char in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_23/hotspot/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/sparsePRT.cpp. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=7285, tid=32
#  Error: char in /BUILD_AREA/jdk6_23/hotspot/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/sparsePRT.cpp
```

Any help is this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @downvoter can you please specify reason for down voting ?

Comment: I've never faced such an issue, but this might help: http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.ch/2012/03/outofmemoryerror-out-of-swap-space.html

Comment: Reduce your -Xmx to 2.5 or 2G, because if you use 3G, you are not leaving any space for JVM native memory usage, and there is very much likelyhood that it will throw out of memory because of JVM native memory exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the operating system has refused the JVM's request to allocate more memory.  The JVM is suggesting the most likely reason for this ... that the operating system has run out of the resources required to "make" virtual memory; i.e. disc space to store physical memory pages when they need to be swapped out.

The fix for this is operating system specific, but it entails increasing the amount of disc space reserved for holding "swapped out" memory pages; i.e. "swap space".